# How to overwrite default pytest parameters in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

Whenever I launch a test inside pycharm it is executed w/ the following parameters:

```
Launching pytest with arguments tests/unittests/routers/test_data.py::TestDataRouter::test_foo --no-header --no-summary -q in ...
```

How do I get rid of the `--no-header --no-summary -q` arguments?

I know I can add arguments in the runtime configuration.  But I cannot find above arguments so I can remove them.  I also checked the configuration templates, nothing in there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can find it here by pressing `ctrl+alt+s` and in advanced setting  Advanced Settings, then select the Pytest: `don't add "--no-header --no-summary -q"` checkbox in the Python section.:
"https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pytest.html#run-pytest-test"